# How get Facebook Sharers from a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know why, sometimes I cannot get sharers from a facebook publication with Graph API.

The error returned is : *(GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported get request.*

My steps are the following:

- I'm using following syntax to get publications from a fan facebook page :

  http://graph.facebook.com/513776871986731/posts
- for each publication, I get id and get the sharers count for id with :

  http://graph.facebook.com/513776871986731_738380319526384?fields=shares

(tihs example show 134 sharers)

- To get sharers name for this post, I'm using this :

  http://graph.facebook.com/738380319526384?fields=sharedposts.fields(from)

and I get the error : *(GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported get request.*

I check all the keys with a debugger :

[image]

But I can't see where is the problem... My goal is the name of the 134 sharers of this publication.

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong ?

Thanks for your help